# Como redireccionar desde la vista o el servidor a otra página html con node js y socket io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Hola estoy haciendo una app con node js y socket.io. He intentado redireccionar a otra página desde la vista pero  no reconoce la página. He visto que en algunas respuestas ponen un código parecido a esto :

```
  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
   response.render('pages/home');    
  });
```

Y posiblemente eso me funcionaría si estuviera usando node js tradicional, es decir, sin socket.io. Pero yo en el servidor tengo algo como esto:

```
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    await socket.on('sesion', async (ok) => {
        //lógica
        await io.to(socket.id).emit('redireccionar');    
    });

    await socket.on('rest', async (payload, entidad) => {

        await Peticion(payload, entidad);

        await io.to(socket.id).emit(RespuestaSocket, PeticionResult);

    });

 
});
```

Y en la vista lo hago como se hace con javascript normal:

```
 window.location.href='login.html';
```

Y el navegador intenta redirigirme pero me sale el error : Cannot GET /login.html

No estoy usando jade ni nada para las vistas es  puro html y mi estructura de proyecto es como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También he intentado hacerlo con express desde el servidor pero tampoco funciona, si se que el socket io hace la comunicación porque me muestra el mensaje (console sesion) en la consola pero no redirige:

```
 await socket.on('sesion', async (ok) => {
        process.stdout.write(`console sesion`);
        app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
 
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
        });

    });
```

Comment: Lo siento, pero no termino de entender la pregunta (o el escenario, para ser preciso). la librería socket.io es para webSockets, si quieres cargar una página web es una llamada http "estándar", con lo que podrías usar ambas cosas (express para servir el HTML y socket.io para comunicarte con esa página una vez cargada)

Comment: No realiza el redireccionamiento ni desde el server ni desde la vista. Acabo de modificar  la pregunta . No soy muy experto en Node js.

Comment: tendrías que manejar las rutas por separado, fuerade socket, de esa manera podes manejar autorizaciones y redireccionar de una manera mantenible y legible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de intentarlo por un tiempo me di cuenta que hay que registrar las rutas y llamarlas sin el .html de la siguiente manera:

```
En el server.js :



 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });


app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});
```

Y en la vista en lugar de usar :

```
location.href='login.html'
```

Se debe poner :

```
location.href="/login"
```

Y de esa forma si funciona.